# Value inside translation yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

### I need return a value inside the translation text in my Rails App. What i have now is something like this:

```
hint: 'Tú código de acceso es #{@customer.passcode}. Este código es de un solo uso.'
```

Comment: what you need is to read the documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) standards you can do the following:

In the view:

```
<%= t('.hint', passcode: @customer.passcode) %>
```

In local.yml file:

```
hint: 'Tú código de acceso es %{passcode}. Este código es de un solo uso.'
```

Answer (score 1):

The interpolation syntax you are using doesn't work in en.yml, change it to

```
hint: 'Tú código de acceso es %{passcode}. Este código es de un solo uso.'
```

And now you can use it as:

```
= I18n.t(:hint, passcode: @customer.passcode)

# OR

= t(:hint, passcode: @customer.passcode)
```